# May I ask my physical equation questions here?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Centripetal Acceleration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471788/centripetal-acceleration)

I'm interested in mathematical-physics and want to ask my equation questions here. So, I'm thinking that I'll post my theoretical questions on physics.se and mathematical questions like equations on math.se May I ask my physical equations on math.se?

Regards!

Comment: The issue I have in trying to respond to that Question (on centripetal acceleration) is that asking to "show an equation to solve it" is a vague request.  If you have given an equation, it still requires some explanation (context) to understand what solving it will amount to.  Which quantity is to be found?  Is it a dynamic (differential) equation with a quantity that changes as a function of time?  Simply writing "an equation" is not the same as asking a good Math.SE Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site is for questions on mathematics. Question on mathematics can be related to or motivated by physics. This is fine.

Questions about physics itself are not really on-topic. For the particular question you asked I feel it is borderline.

If you had stated an equation and asked how to solve it given some data, then I would have said that's fine. This is a mathematical problem motivated by physics.

However, answering your problem requires mostly knowledge about what are the equations relating certain physical quantities. To know these equations requires knowledge of physics not mathematics.

The question how to derive an equation from other principles is more on-topic if it involves mathematical reasoning. Your question had a bit of that, so let's say it is fine for this time.

But generally for this site please:

1. Ask how to solve equations.
2. Ask how to transform  specific equations into other equations. (Or, maybe even how to obtain equations from first principles, in the sense of mathematical modeling.)
3. Do not ask the equation for some physics notion.

Your current question was somewhere between 2. and 3.

Comment: (+1) especially to the part "To know these equations requires knowledge of physics, not mathematics." Take the physics parts out and ask the math questions and you'll be on-topic for this site.